# I have to face this exception when i am use Oauth for android subscirption : 403 User Rate Limit Exceeded

Tags: java, android, oauth, google-api, subscription

```
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 403 User Rate Limit Exceeded
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>User Rate Limit Exceeded</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>User Rate Limit Exceeded</H1>
<H2>Error 403</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>

    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Tenter code hereokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:103)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:303)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:323)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:340)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:505)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.handleResponse(Credential.java:292)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1023)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.execute(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:182)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.GoogleClient.executeUnparsed(GoogleClient.java:279)
    at com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpRequest.executeUnparsed(JsonHttpRequest.java:207)
    at com.google.api.services.androidpublisher.Androidpublisher$Purchases$Get.execute(Androidpublisher.java:416)
    at com.uks.jbipaper.android.Subscription.subscriptionVerification(Subscription.java:71)
    at com.uks.jbipaper.android.Subscription.main(Subscription.java:29)
```

**My Example Code is:**

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT).setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY).setServiceAccountId(Constants.ACCOUNT_ID).setServiceAccountScopes(Constants.ACCOUNT_SCOPE).setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File( Constants.P12)).build();

Androidpublisher publisher = new Androidpublisher.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT,JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(Constants.APP_NAME).build();
Androidpublisher.Purchases purchases = publisher.purchases();
Get get = purchases.get(Constants.APP_PACKAGE_NAME,"android.test.purchased", Constants.TOKEN);
SubscriptionPurchase subscripcion = get.execute();
```

Comment: This is often a symptom of not having registered your app, or not having identified it to the API.Did you done this?